# I've made a batch file that's meant to display a list and its sublist but it doesn't work

Tags: batch-file

Every entry in the main list is written in a new line, while every entry in a sublist is separated with a comma in the file. The first entry of a sublist is its title. Something like: title,entry,entry each line, with a dynamic number of entries. Sorry for newbie mistakes, I'm pretty new to this. Also sorry if it was asked before (couldn't find anything like that myself).

What i've written looks like this and I have no idea why doesn't it work:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in (list.txt) do (
    set chos=%%G
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=," %%H in ("!chos!") echo %%H:
    set chos=!chos:,=^

    !
    for /F "tokens=* skip=1" %%I in ("!chos!") echo    - %%I
)
pause >nul
```

Comment: Providing an example of your list would help as well. Sometimes descriptions just do not give enough detail. Always best to give as much information as possible. When troubleshooting a batch file , turn echo on and run the batch file from the cmd prompt so that you can see the errors.

Comment: If you could show me what the input looks like and what the output is supposed to look like you can probably shorten up this code by a few lines. I have seen this technique used before and I could show you how to shorten it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you miss "do" before echo

```
for /F "tokens=1 delims=," %%H in ("!chos!") do echo %%H:
```

A black window will flash away when the batchfile has some errors. Calling batchfile in the cmd.exe will keep the error message.

edit: You can also do it in this way:

```
@echo off&SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in (list.txt) do (
    for /F "tokens=1,* delims=," %%H in ("%%G") do (
      echo %%H
      for  %%a in (%%I) do (
        echo   -%%a
      )
    )
)
pause
```

Comment: Thanks, but the 3rd for still doesn't work, do you know why?

Comment: @Enexin   do you add "do" before echo?

Comment: @Enexin - Seriously!? If you cannot debug that short amount of code with information already provided, then you should seriously consider leaving programming to others.

Comment: turns out it didn't work because of that tab before ! also, dbenham do you really need to be rude? .-. everyone used to be new to something, you know

Comment: Hmm. Always thought tab and spaces were treated the same.

Comment: @Enexin - to be fair, if it _had_ turned out to be you missing a `do`, you would have been asking a really stupid question.

Comment: @Enexin - Tabs before the `!` do not cause any problem. The code works fine with tabs before the `!` if you put DO where it belongs. But it will fail if there is a tab on  the "empty" line before the closing `!`. To work properly, the line must be truly empty. And yes, for some reason I am not in a charitable mood. Sorry about that. Perhaps it is the 64 oz of 8% beer I consumed this evening.